# Count multiple div class in same page

Tags: javascript, class, counter

I am trying to make a correct and incorrect question counter that shows groups of 4.

If I click on the first correct answer the counter works correctly and increases as I click, but it does not work with the second correct answer. The same happens with the wrong answers

This is the codes that I use, anyone could help me? Thx

**HTML CODE:**

```
    ¿Which of the following operations results in 8?
<input class="solucioncorrecta" value="6+2">
<input class="solucioncorrecta" value="7+1">
<input class="solucionincorrecta" value="1+1">
<input class="solucionincorrecta" value="2+2">
```

**And the JS CODE:**

```
<!-- CONTADOR FALLOS TEST -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var root = document.querySelector('.solucionincorrecta');

root.onclick = function() { 
var elem = document.getElementById('contadorfallos');
  elem.innerHTML = +elem.innerText + 1;
};
</script>
<!-- CONTADOR FALLOS TEST -->


<!-- CONTADOR ACIERTOS TEST -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var root = document.querySelector('.solucioncorrecta');

root.onclick = function() { 
var elem = document.getElementById('contadoraciertos');
  elem.innerHTML = +elem.innerText + 1;
};
</script>
```

Comment: Have you googled on how to change an INPUT `value`? `innerHTML`, `textContent` and `innerText` are not the right tools.

Comment: To clarify, your click is working on the first `.correcta` but not on the other ones?

Comment: Instead of showing us some arbitrary `{text}` placeholder, could you please create a [mcve]?

Comment: No, sorry, look for a similar code on this website and try to adapt it to my needs, I barely have knowledge of JS

Comment: Where is ID `contadoraciertos` ins your HTML example?

Comment: It works when I click on the first correct answer, i.e. the one in the first div, and it increments the counter as I click. Instead if I click on the second div which is also a correct answer, the counter doesn't work.

Comment: I update my example code

Comment: What is button in your code?, you are using `querySelector` which returns a single element but there is two elements with same class.

Comment: Sorry Elvis, I have changed the code the code in my first answer and added a link.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using `document.querySelector()` and not `document.querySelectorAll()`

`document.querySelector()` Returns the first match

`document.querySelectorAll()` Returns all matches

As a result, you are only setting an `onclick` property on the first `.correcta` and `.incorrecta` elements, not all of them.

To set this on all of them, you need to do two things:

1. You need use `document.querySelectorAll()` instead of `document.querySelector()`. This returns a list (specifically, a `NodeList`) of matching elements.
2. Loop over the items in your list, and attach `onclick` handlers to each of them. There are many ways to loop over a NodeList, [listed here](https://css-tricks.com/a-bunch-of-options-for-looping-over-queryselectorall-nodelists/).

Here is an example:

```js
// get all incorrect elements
var incorrectElements = document.querySelectorAll('.incorrecta');

// loop over each elements
for (var element of incorrectElements) {
  // add an onclick
  element.onclick = incorrectClickHandler
}

// this is the function being called by onclick
function incorrectClickHandler() {
  score.innerText = parseInt(score.innerText) - 1;
}
```

Comment: Thx!!

I have changed the code the code in my first answer and I have put an example link to my website. I also tried to change document.querySelector() to document.querySelectorAll() and add the code that you have told me but it doesn't seem to work, I'm a bit useless :(

Comment: I recommend you add console.log() statements to help you debug which parts of your code are and are not working

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you upload your full codes. But anyway I write you some notes that probably answer your question.

-dont use the same name (root) for your `.correcta`  and `.incorrecta`

-in your second `<script>`, you didnt defined `button` as an object . So browser cant understand it.

Comment: Thx!
I have changed the code the code in my first answer and added a link.